# amd ryzen mobile 2nd gen suitable with ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 19.04, amd-ryzen

sorry for my poor english.

I bought a laptop machine with amd ryzen 7 3700u(hp envy x360 13 2019 model) and tried to install ubuntu 19.04.
but installation always failed. after grub, the screen went to black.

I also tried some grub option `nomodeset`, `nosplash`, `amdgpu.runpm=0`, but  all options were useless.

is the 2nd amd ryzen mobile cpu not suitable for ubuntu?
there are no way to install ubuntu to my machine?

help me please wizards/

Comment: AMD had a recall for some of their processors that had problems with Linux. You might check their web site to see if yours was recalled.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet (as of beginning of August). HP has messed-up ACPI BIOS configuration. This is issue with Linux kernel.

It is possible to make it work, though. Please, see my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1163672/686899

Comment: thank you for information. I tried to install linux mint 19.1 with solution1, anyhow successfully installed(I couldn't install ubuntu from version 18.04 to 19.04...)

And I tried to solution 2, but failed...
I put the command `sudo acpidump -b` to get acpi tables in linux, but the return was `there are no such directory /sys/lib/firmware/acpi/tables`

How can I get acpi tables?

Comment: Hello @mududori8. Congratulations for making it work! ACPI can be extracted from BIOS/UEFI only from operating system which is running with ACPI enabled on the same machine. So if you Ubuntu is currently running only with "nolapic acpi=off", it cannot be used to extract ACPI from BIOS. That is why one of my first sentences hinted: "Do not delete pre-installed windows" :) Do you have Windows still working/installed? If yes, then try windows version of 'acpidump.exe' to extract ACPI tables :) Which version of HP ENVY do you have? I have this working on 15-ds0005 and 15-ds0003ur.